# Stored Procedure Fails in IIS ASP.NET Web App - Runs Fine in Management Studio AND 32bit SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that is run once at the end of each month to produce files used for reporting.  It has no input parameters and only one output parameter which returns a character value as to whether or not it completed successfully.

The SP makes use of cursors and they are all deallocated when I'm finished with them.

The Stored procedure has been running with no issues on the same server for two years - the server is Windows 2008 R2 64bit with 8GB of RAM.

The SQL Server is SQL Server 2008 R2 64bit.

I can run the stored procedure on the same server using the SQL Management Studio with no problems at all.

I made a copy of the database on an older SQL Server R2 32bit machine and found that it runs fine from BOTH the Web App and the 32bit Management Studio.

Some articles mentioined setting "arithabort" - I've set this paramater to both on and off and it still failed in the same way.

The Stored Procedure uses "WITH RECOMPILE" which solved another problem for me years ago.

When run from the Management Studio the SP takes about 30 seconds to run to completion - when run from the web server it takes much longer and then fails.

I have not made any changes to the server settings since I've never had problems.

Comment: You didn't tell us what the error message is.

Comment: your description of the issue is preventing any help. a stored procedure can do almost everything: update, insert, delete, copy. and how much data you are handling? hundreds of rows? billions? also your description 'it takes much longer and then fails' is of little help describing your problem. technical detail are needed...

Comment: Currently the procedure is returning a message that it failed - I will see if I can get an actual SQL error message and I'll post it here.

Thanks!

Comment: What changed?  If you say nothing.. I say you're wrong.  Something obviously did.

Comment: Good point - the customer's business has picked up a little and so there are more invoices being created than before.  We may have hit a "magic number" that causes the failure!

Comment: I needed to create some code to trap this error since it isn't a problem in Visual Studio it only happens when the SP is run on the server.  I have written a routine that I will put into the stored procedure so I can get the SQL @@error number AND the place in the code that failed. I will need to do this over the weekend and I'll report back my findings ASAP!  Thanks to all who are helping!

Comment: I made some program changes to the Stored Procedure that is crashing in order to trap an error.  Unfortunately when it crashes on the 64bit server it never returns any error information.  Also, nothing is written in the SQL Logs or even the Server's Event Log.  The SP continues to run fine on the old 32bit server with 1GB of RAM, also in Visual Studio and from the SQL Management Console.

Comment: I checked my SP to verify that there wasn't something wrong - like a "flood" of records and there isn't.  The SP uses several cursors and updates about 3,000 records.  I'm at a loss as to where to go next and would appreciate any ideas.  Thanks Very Much!

Comment: I built a BRAND NEW Windows 2008 R2 box and installed SQL Server 2008 R2.  The SP that I'm calling runs FINE from both the management console AND my web application.  Given this does anyone have suggestions as to what could be wrong with the original 64bit server discussed above?  Thanks!